# Makefile doing "too much work"

Tags: unix, gcc, makefile

For my assignment, we are supposed to compile cpp2html.c to produce cpp2html.o. We are to do the same thing with lex.yy.c. lex.yy.c is created by the command flex cppscanner.l. Lastly, we're supposed to link the .o files together to produce an executable program named cpp2html.
My makefile is supposed to use gcc instead of g++, which I *believe* I am doing correctly. I've tried to get this specific makefile to work for this program for a few hours now, as the one for the g++ portion worked fine. When I submit this makefile, I'm told that "Your makefile does too much work when only cpp2html.c has been changed." I tried looking up this error, and was only able to find someone who had the error on the g++ portion; I tried adapting it, but it didn't work. I've tried changing the format of the makefile, I've tried altering the codes, but I just don't know what I'm doing wrong.

How can I alter my makefile to do what it needs to, without making it do "too much work"?

My makefile is as follows.

```
cpp2html: cpp2html.o lex.yy.o
    gcc -g -DDEBUG cpp2html.o lex.yy.o
    mv a.out cpp2html
cpp2html.o: cpp2html.c
    gcc -g -DDEBUG -c cpp2html.c
    flex cppscanner.l
lex.yy.o: lex.yy.c
    gcc -g -c lex.yy.c
```

EDIT:

```
cpp2html: cpp2html.o lex.yy.o
    gcc -g cpp2html.o lex.yy.o
    gcc -g -DDEBUG cpp2html.o lex.yy.o -o cpp2html
cpp2html.o: cpp2html.c
    gcc -g -c cpp2html.c
lex.yy.c: cppscanner.l
    flex cppscanner.l
lex.yy.o: lex.yy.c
    gcc -g -c lex.yy.c
```

Comment: instead of `mv` you can use `-o` option of `gcc`. Use `-o cpp2html`. Also put `flex` command in a separate target.

Comment: shiplu, I replaced the entire line "mv a.out cpp2html" with "-o cpp2html", and now it's saying that my makefile doesnt even build cpp2html. What do you mean by put flex in a seperate target?

Comment: Remove the entire `mv` line and use this command ` gcc -g -DDEBUG cpp2html.o lex.yy.o -o cpp2html`. For `flex` create a separate target. `lex.yy.c: cppscanner.1` with command `flex cppscanner.l`.

Comment: Ok, I did that. I completely replaced the mv line like you said, and for flex, I wasn't entirely sure what you meant, (still learning), so I put in `lex.yy.c: cppscanner.l` and then i made a new line below that, hit tab, and then entered `flex cppscanner.l`. It gives me the same "doing too much work" error, but I probably misinterpreted what you said

Comment: `cpp2html.o` taget should have only the `gcc` command not the flex part.

Comment: I didn't do anything to `cpp2html.o`. I'm editing my original post to show the code I have now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This makefile should resolve this,

```
cpp2html: cpp2html.o lex.yy.o
    gcc -g -DDEBUG cpp2html.o lex.yy.o -o cpp2html

cpp2html.o: cpp2html.c
    gcc -g -DDEBUG -c cpp2html.c

lex.yy.o: lex.yy.c
    gcc -g -c lex.yy.c

lex.yy.c: cppscanner.l
    flex cppscanner.l -o lex.yy.c
```

Comment: I tried this, entered it in exactly as you wrote it and am getting "ERROR: end of file in string" "make: **** [lex.yy.c] Error 1" Additionally, it says that the makefile doesn't build 'cpp2html' when invoked. Is lex.yy.c supposed to have a blank line? I'm going to try running it without that blank line right after the colon, but I'm not sure if that's it.

Comment: I was able to get it to work by putting in cppscanner.l for the initial line after the colon, another with the command flex cppscanner.l, and another one with the -o line.

Comment: @JoJoBya sorry, I was in hurry so did some mistake. I have just updated the makefile. This should do it.